# dplyr Summarise improperly excluding NA

Tags: r, dplyr

We can group mtcars by cylinder and summarize miles per gallon with some simple code.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(mpg))
```

This provides the correct output shown below.

```
    cyl      avg
1     4 26.66364
2     6 19.74286
3     8 15.10000
```

If I kindly ask dplyr to exclude NA I get some weird results.

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(!is.na(mpg)))
```

Since there are no NA in this data set the results should be the same as above. But it averages all mpg to exactly "1". **A problem with my code or a bug in dplyr?**

```
    cyl   avg
1     4     1
2     6     1
3     8     1
```

My actual data set does have some NA that I need to exclude only for this summarization, but exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: You're taking the mean of a `logical` value, not a numeric one when you do `mean(!is.na(mpg))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
mtcars %>% 
group_by(cyl) %>% 
summarise(avg = mean(mpg, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl      avg
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     4 26.66364
2     6 19.74286
3     8 15.10000
```

Right now, you're returning a `logical` vector with `!is.na(mpg)`. When you take the `mean()` of a `logical` vector, it'll be coerced to 1, not the `numeric` value you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have coded it, the input to the `mean()` function is a vector of TRUE and FALSE values. Use `mean(mpg[!is.na(mpg)])` instead.

Consider using `data.table` which I have used for illustration purposes. The following all produce the same result.

```
library(data.table)
MT[, mean(mpg), by = cyl]
   cyl       V1
1:   6 19.74286
2:   4 26.66364
3:   8 15.10000

MT[, mean(mpg, na.rm=TRUE), by = cyl]
   cyl       V1
1:   6 19.74286
2:   4 26.66364
3:   8 15.10000

MT[, mean(mpg[!is.na(mpg)]), by = cyl]
   cyl       V1
1:   6 19.74286
2:   4 26.66364
3:   8 15.10000
```